# VB.net not picking up data from xml

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to read a  XML file and put its text as a textbox text. I am unable to do this, it is showing this error : 'Text' is an invalid XmlNodeType. Line 1, position 31.'

Looks like I am missing something basic. Appreciate any help.

This is my XML file:

```
<root>
<doc>
<name1 name="name">Shashwat</name1>
<age name="age">21</age>

</doc>
</root>
```

And this my code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form6

    Private Sub Form6_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim m_xmlr As XmlTextReader

        m_xmlr = New XmlTextReader("D:\register.xml")

        m_xmlr.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None

        m_xmlr.Read()



        While Not m_xmlr.EOF

            m_xmlr.Read()

            If Not m_xmlr.IsStartElement() Then
                Exit While
            End If

            Dim nameAttribute = m_xmlr.GetAttribute("doc")

            m_xmlr.Read()

            Dim firstNameValue = m_xmlr.ReadElementString("name1")

            Dim ageValue = m_xmlr.ReadElementString("age")

            TextBox1.Text = firstNameValue
            TextBox2.Text = ageValue

        End While

        m_xmlr.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Try removing the blank line and see if that helps.

Comment: Just made a quick app with your code and XML and it worked without any issues for me.  I'm guessing it's a whitespace issue, or maybe you want to put the XML prefix node at the top.  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?> or something.  There's nothing wrong with your code

Comment: Thank you. the error was I didn't have the line <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more simple approach using XDocument/XElement:

```
Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("D:\register.xml")
Dim doc As XElement = xDoc.Element("doc")

Dim nameAttribute As String = doc.Element("name1").Value
Dim ageValue As String = doc.Element("age").Value
```

Comment: This is generating error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." :(

Comment: @user2922822: On which line? It may be a problem with your xml file. Check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML, and notice `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it was suggestion given by phil

I added this line in the beginning of the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
```